# Expo iOS app: How to see console logs in `--no-dev minify` or preview build?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm sorting through all the different build options Expo has - very powerful and flexible, but very confusing!

Here are 2 ways I've tried building my app, which I know are different:

1. `npx expo start --no-dev --minify` - which I can then run in iOS Simulator
2. `eas build -p ios --profile preview` - which I can then download and pop into iOS Simulator

In both of these methods, how do I see console logs? In other methods involving the iOS Simulator, I learned that I can open Safari > Develop > Simulator > JSContext to see the logs. But while I can open that for the two options above, no logs appear.

Comment: You can always redirect your logs to a file in Production Mode. See [Output Logs to a file](https://blog.logrocket.com/reviewing-react-native-console-logs-best-practices/). You should note that your 1st approach is the Production Mode, which is not for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. So the file with outputted logs would be stored on the device somewhere? I presume there's a way to get these out of the iOS Simulator to take a look? Also, when you say the 1st approach is Production Mode, does that imply Production Mode never outputs console.logs unless you make the logs go elsewhere? And #2 that I mentioned is not considered Production Mode?

Comment: Yes, you can extract the files from the iOS Simulator, it's at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`. "Production Mode does not output logs" The official documentation doesn't tell the answers.